# How to copy text and newlines in JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some text like this

```
text = 'line 1' + "\r\n";
text+= 'line 2' + "\r\n";
text+= 'line 3' + "\r\n";
```

I use this function to copy it to clipboard

```
function copyToClipboard(text)
{

    var copyElement = document.createElement("span");
    copyElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    copyElement.id = 'tempCopyToClipboard';
    angular.element(document.body.append(copyElement));

    // select the text
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(copyElement);
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);

    // copy & cleanup
    document.execCommand('copy');
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    copyElement.remove();
}
```

how can I copy this to clipboard without loosing the newline?

Answer (score 0):

sorry all, my bad
I copied this snippet but I just realized I should use a textarea and not a span.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like its working for me when I define the text inside your function. Are you sure the new lines are getting passed into the function as you expect?

```js
function copyToClipboard()
{
    var text = 'line 1' + "\r\n";
    text+= 'line 2' + "\r\n";
    text+= 'line 3' + "\r\n";
    
    var copyElement = document.createElement("span");
    copyElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    copyElement.id = 'tempCopyToClipboard';
    angular.element(document.body.append(copyElement));

    // select the text
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(copyElement);
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);

    // copy & cleanup
    document.execCommand('copy');
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    copyElement.remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" onclick="copyToClipboard()">Copy text to clipboard</button>
```

Comment: what are you pasting into? Notepad++ interprets the new line but looks like notepad does not. Do you have control over what line endings you can use?

Comment: I tried notepad, MS word, MS outlook. yes I do I tried "\n" but no luck

Comment: If you paste into MS Word and use the paste option "keep text only", the line breaks are preserved. MS Word should accept CRLF, which is what you have, so not sure why it automatically strips it on paste